# Chrome is rendering .txt files

Tags: google-chrome

All of a sudden, chrome (v 23.0) began rendering .txt files used to debug curl http requests. There is javascript and html in these files that used to be displayed as text. Now, some of the javascript is causing a redirect. Safari and Firefox are still working as before.

I'm concluding that this is a setting, but did not find any thing related in Chrome settings.

Any ideas where to change a setting like this.

**Edit:** HTTP Headers:

```
Request URL:https://mysite.com/debug/checkin_cron/checkin_cron_bu_913.txt
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:
Host:mysite.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:47520
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Fri, 14 Dec 2012 23:09:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=3, max=100
Last-Modified:Fri, 14 Dec 2012 22:28:31 GMT
Server:Apache
```

Comment: Can you post the HTTP header of the response?  What's the MIME type (content-type) set to?

Comment: Of all the funny reasons... I added Skype links extension to chrome earlier today. Disabling it makes the problem go away. Sure would like to have both.

Comment: Ah, that's an odd one indeed..

Comment: I guess it's time to write the author there. @MikeChristensen your first comment causes me to wonder... Maybe the MIME type could override the extension ??? I don't think one is being set for these .txt files.

Comment: Ideally, if you do a `curl --head http://yourserver/blah.txt` you should get back a `Context-Type: text/plain`, which would cause Chrome to render it as text.  If that header is missing, I believe it's operating system specific on how the extension is handled.  Maybe Skype changed the MIME type for `.txt` files or something.

Comment: Weird, so the `content-type` header is correct, but the Skype extension somehow prevents the content from being rendered as text.  I can't really help you then.  Complain to whoever wrote the extension I guess :)

Comment: Filed a comment on github for the author.